# Problema con blade al mostrar espacios

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo una colección de objetos que se han recuperado de un modelo llamado `Persona`. Entre las propiedades hay una que se llama `nombre`. En el controlador la precedo con cuatro espacios "duros" (`&nbsp;`), porque la necesito indentada en la vista. Siempre me han dicho que es mejor procesar lo más posible los datos en el controlador, y evitar, en lo posible, manipularlos en la vista, que la vista debe limitarse a mostrar lo que le llega del controlador.

Cuando llego a la vista, intento mostrar esa propiedad, así:

```
{{ $persona->nombre }}
```

El problema es que Blade me sustituye el `&` de `&nbsp;` por `&amp;`. Resultado: En lugar de obtener `Pedro` con cuatro espacios delante, obtengo en pantalla `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pedro`.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la vista me muestre los espacios correctamente? Si en el controlador uso espacios "normales", ya sabemos que HTML los ignora, por lo que no se muestra la indentación, así que tengo que usar espacios duros, pero necesito que la vista los muestre como tales, no como el literal de las entidades.

Por lo que veo, el problema viene porque Blade muestra los datos interpolados usando el helper `e()`, que incorpora la función `htmlspecialchars` de PHP. ¿Cuál sería la mejor forma de mostrar los datos "tal como vienen", sin que se meta ese helper de por medio? Estoy segura de que tiene que haber alguna función o helper, pero llevo horas mirando la documentación y no veo nada adecuado.

Comment: y porque no asi lo pones directamente en la view?? `@if($persona->nombre)
  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ $persona->nombre }} 
@endif` o puedes solo hacer: `&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $persona->nombre }}` o con propiedades `css` contaminas todo tu codigo por 4 espacios :V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta para no hacer el "escape" de datos en blade es con `{!! !!}`, así que el código quedaría así:

```
{!! $persona->nombre !!}
```

Comment: He buscado en Internet lo que me comentas. Funcionar, funciona, pero dicen que abre un agujero de seguridad para algo que llaman XSS. ¿Es cierto esto? ¿Supone una vulnerabilidad?

Comment: Sí, es cierto y posible, por lo cual debe usarse únicamente con información que no recibas del usuario o que filtres previamente.